# add new input after button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to have a button which will add a new text and input each time after the button is clicked.

Desired output after the button is clicked once.

[image]

But given my following codes, my new input will override the initial input.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Input
          <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="form-group row" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
      <button id="addnewinputbtn" name="button" class="btn btn-default">Add New Input</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#addnewinputbtn').click(function() {
        $('tr').appendTo('tbody')
          .html(
            '<td>New Input <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"></td>');
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code

```
 $('tr').appendTo('tbody').html(
   '<td>New Input <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"></td>');
 });
```

.html() on tr will  replace the html of tr element with the new input td element , you should append the new input td element in the tr element.

Edited: This code will replace the html of the tr element in the DOM since the selector $('tr') will select the tr element present in the DOM.

```
$('tr').appendTo('tbody')
          .html(
            '<td>New Input <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"></td>');
      });
```

but if you wan to create a new tr element, the code should be

$('').appendTo('tbody')
              .html(
                'New Input ');
          });

$('') will create a new element.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Input
          <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="form-group row" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
      <button id="addnewinputbtn" name="button" class="btn btn-default">Add New Input</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
      .ready(
        function() {
          $('#addnewinputbtn')
            .click(
              function() {
                
         $('<tr>').appendTo('tbody').html(
            '<td>New Input <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"></td>');
      });

        });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But its appending to the side of the pervious input. I want it to append below the pervious input.

Comment: do you want a new row? you code looks like its trying to add a new td.

Comment: @TestAccount updated the example to  add a new row instead of a td element.

Comment: @TestAccount , i have also updated the reason why your code was not working. Its a small miss in your code but change the functionality all together.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Table</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Input
          <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div class="form-group row" style="padding-top: 10px">
    <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
      <button id="addnewinputbtn" name="button" class="btn btn-default">Add New Input</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document)
      .ready(
        function() {
          $('#addnewinputbtn')
            .click(
              function() {
                $('tbody')
                  .append(
                    '<tr><td>New Input <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>');

              });
        });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: But its appending to the side of the pervious input. I want it to append below the pervious input.

Comment: @TestAccount Now test it

Answer (score 0):

Try doing appending it do the `tr` instead like so:

```
$('tr').append(...);
```

That will append a new element nested in the tr tag instead of appending a new element to the body thus overriding itself

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery `append` to add another element.

```js
function AddTextBox(){
  $("#populateInput").append('<input type="text" class="customControl"/>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="AddTextBox()">Add Input</button>
<div id="populateInput">
  </div>
```